# Errors not being thrown

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, oop, typescript

I have what seems to be an oddball situation. I have just started experimenting with Typescript, and I am trying to implement an interface for use with NodeJS. I have created a "find" function, which returns all the results from a MongoDB collection. However, the results are not returned in the way that I expect them. For example, the only way the code below works is if I do "res.send(err)", as that variable contains the results of the query. The "results" variable comes back as undefined.

What I would like to know is two fold:

1) What did I do wrong?
2) How can I get the callback to properly display the error and results?

Interface:

```
interface ICallback{
    (error: string, results: string): void;
}

export interface IDatabase{
    find(db: string, callback : ICallback) : void;
}
```

Mongo Class

```
export class MongoDB extends Database implements IDatabase{
    //...
    find(collection, callback){
        db.find().toArray(function(err, docs){
            if(err){
                callback(err);
            }
           callback(docs);
       });
   };
}
```

Node Controller

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {

    //... instantiate new db, connect, get the collection, assign to
   // thisColl variable

    dbInstance.find(thisColl, function(err, results){
        if(err){
           return err; //contains the actual results
        };
        res.send(results); //comes back undefined
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Mongo class, if the call is successful you're calling your callback with `callback(docs);`. But the 1st argument is an error, not the result! What you want is `callback(null, docs);`.

Typescript would have caught this error for you if you had added typings to your query callback. Ie.

```
// before
function(err, docs)

// after
function(err: Error, docs: Doc[])
```

Comment: Ah! Yes, I see it now, thanks for catching it! In regards to the typings: thank for for showing me the Error type. I have not read too deeply regarding type yet, but that "Error" type belongs to a Node Interface, so it worked well, especially for "code sense". As for the docs, wouldn't this be more appropriate?  "docs: Array<string>"...The code you mentioned before errors with "cannot find name Doc".

Comment: `Array<string>` is perfect (in fact, it's good style to use the condensed syntax `string[]`). i assumed the result is an array of objects.

Comment: Ok, great. Yes, an array of objects is being returned. With regards to style/convention, is it best practice to create an interface such as ICallback, and then reference that Type for the IDatabase find method callback parameter?

Comment: No need for `IDatabase` at all - declaring a `Database` class generates both a type (ie. the same thing that `IDatabase` generates) and a value. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#81-class-declarations

Comment: One final thought. As I am using typescript, and the definitely typed system, would the best approach to assigning types be as follows for the error? Found at: [Mongo Typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cc3d223a946f661eff871787edeb0fcb8f0db156/mongodb/mongodb-tests.ts)

Comment: Exactly. I was using `Error` as a stub for whatever more specific error type you are using. In your case `MongoError` is that more specific type.